# Magento 1.9 multiple websites on different domains

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, server-setup, websites, apache

I read and viewed all things related to multiple websites for Magento, but I still cannot setup properly to handle different domains with different Magento websites.

Could somebody let me know step by step, how to setup the virtual hosts properly and htaccess or/and index.php?

I know that setting multiple websites in subdomains/catalogs is easy, but I like it to work with different domains.

I have set up everything in Magento admin:

#### 1st store:

- domain: abc.com
- website code: domain1

#### 2nd store:

- domain: xyz.com
- website code: domain2

I have Apache configured in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` with the following document roots:

- /home/admin/domains/abc.com/public_html
- /home/admin/domains/xyz.com/public_html

What should I put in the second domain directory (.htaccess, index.php? should I copy it from first one?)

Comment: What kind of 404 are you getting? a 404 with Magento style or directly from the server?

Comment: Why do you want a second domain directory? Magento is built to handle multiple store views. You should use the same document root for both sites and just set the website/store code as an environment variable in your Apache configuration for each site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find how to setup multiple storefronts on one Magento installation by following:
http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/

This method works for any store post Magento CE 1.4

Look to the end of the article you will see there are two methods, one that uses separate directories for each domain and a second method that allows you to use pointer domains.

If you are looking to have customers checkout on the store domain and not one shared domain under SSL you will want to use the separate directories method. It describes how to setup the symbolic links so the store will properly pull files and how to modify the the index.php of each store to assign the correct website/store code.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to have multiple directories for multiple domains if you are using single magento instance to fulfill your requirements.

**Step 1:** Point all domains to Magento root directory, i.e. same document root in the webserver (Apache or Nginx) configuration.

**Step 2:** Configure domain names as base URLs for each website in System Configuration in Magento admin panel.

**Step 3:** Set store or website for each domain as environment variable in `.htaccess` or in the webserver configuration.

- Example with the websites as given in the question:

  ```
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website
  SetEnvIf Host abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain1
  SetEnvIf Host xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
  ```
- Example with store views instead of websites

  ```
  SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE store
  SetEnvIf Host abc\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_code_1
  SetEnvIf Host xyz\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store_code_2
  ```

  These configurations check if the domain **contains** "abc.com" or "xyz.com", which I find useful to also match subdomains or test systems like abc.com.testserver.com or test.abc.com, using the same .htaccess file. If you want exact matching, replace `abc\.com` with `^abc\.com$`

**Step 4:** Clear cache and access your domains.

Comment: I added some details to make it the canonical answer I would expect, hope you don't mind

Comment: Change is good, if it for good. Thanx :)

Comment: when i write SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE website line in my .htaccess file site not open it gives error 500

Comment: can you share what have you added in your .htaccess file @jigsparmar

Answer (score 2):

You should copy `index.php` and `.htaccess` files on your second domain directory.

After that:

Open up the `index.php` file and look for this line (it's the last line of the file):

> `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

Add the following code right before the above code:

> `$mageRunCode = 'YOUR_WEBSITE_CODE';`
>
> `$mageRunType = 'website';`

Lastly, you need to create symbolic links to point to a few directories:

> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/app ./app
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/errors ./errors
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/includes ./includes
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/js ./js
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/lib ./lib
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/media ./media
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/skin ./skin
>
> ln -s your_magento_root_directory/var ./var

Source: http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/how-to-setup-multiple-magento-stores/

Comment: How can i run above commands in windows

Answer (score 2):

You can follow below steps to configure your multi store in magento:

1) All domains which you are adding as another domains like `xyz.com`, point this domain to your main magento website url `abc.com`
2) open your admin panel, and add website, Store and Store view in your Manage Store
3) open your .htaccess file and add below code

> SetEnvIf Host .*xyz.com.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=domain2
>   SetEnvIf Host .*xyz.com.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

4) Go to configurations > Web, change your store view and add your domain url's there.
5) Save and clear cache

This will configure multi website. Let me know if this will work for you.