# Deleted Website - setWebsite() error

Tags: database

I deleted a website instance via the Magento Backend. Since then I get this error:

```
Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Model_Store::setWebsite() must be an instance of Mage_Core_Model_Website, null given
```

I already deleted everything in the var/cache folder and also executed this query without success:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

The file `app/etc/use_cache.ser` is not existent.

Do you have any advice how to get rid of the above mentioned error?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your index.php or htaccess if you're not trying to run a website code that has been deleted. If it was used in a extension or template file this will be an issue as well.

Comment: I can not find anything in the index.php which is related to the old store that I have deleted. Where in the htaccess could be possibly something inserted which has to do with the other stores? @versedi

Comment: Check this answer: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121952/13907

or if using 2: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html