# Magento 1.9.2 - store view in multiple domain

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, stores, multidomain

I have a unique website with two store views for two languages ​​(Italian and English). For store view of the first language I would like to keep it in the address www.mysite.it while the second one I want to call it from external domain with the address www.mysite.com.

My question is: To recall the second store view from the external domain (www.mysite.com), is it sufficient to modify the index.php file in the root of the site or do we also need to modify the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe your website structure would not allow to do so. You need to look at the [official documentation](https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/stores-multiple.html) to setup your store.

Comment: So if I wanted to put my shop on another domain I can't?

Do I have to create a new website? Because I saw some users who managed to manage the second language even on an external domain ...

Comment: Yes, magento does not allow you to add domain with the store view, you need to create separate website  for each domain , If you have two domains its mean you have to create two websites. than you may create store and store views according to your requirement

Comment: May be these answer would be helpful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32439/magento-1-9-multiple-websites-on-different-domains